# OSX CoreData data issues

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` that I use binding to an `ArrayController` and I'm able to open a directory and display the files within the table just fine.  I also have a column that holds an image.  I quit the application and go back in and the file list is still there which is what I want!

Now the part I'm having issues is, I change the image on button press and close the app and reopen it the old image is there and not the new one.  Also the image name's are null.

This is how I update the images in the CoreData

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects =[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSManagedObject *object = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:currentAudioIndex];



    NSImage *image = [object valueForKey:@"taggedImage"];


    if ([[image name] isEqualToString:@"tag_green"]) {
        NSImage *tagImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"tag_red.png"];
        [object setValue:tagImage forKey:@"taggedImage"];
    }
```

When opening a directory and getting a list of files, i am able to change images and the table is updated, but when I close the app and reopen it the files are there, changed images aren't and when I try to change the image with the code above it says the image name is `NULL`.

Comment: you're talking about NSTableView and ***not*** UITableView, which exists only under iOS

Comment: you're correct! I'm coming from an iOS background so I get confused at times. Thanks.

Comment: which line says image name is null?  do you get a valid image from your "`[object valueForKey:@"taggedImage"];`" line after you reopen the app?  Where/when do you save your changes to the managed object?

Comment: It says Null when I do a  NSLog(@"image name: %@", [image name]);   Seems like the app saves automatically when I close it because I didn't write any code to save the filenames but they are there when I open them.

Comment: Looks like code is setup to save in the function - (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender

Comment: try saving your object right *after* changing the image.